# Took time to put in a thorough question, stated my issue clearly, and still put on hold

Tags: discussion

I posted this earlier: [Is a tag based system a better UX than traditional folder structure?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93832/converting-users-from-hierarchical-structure-to-tags) and was surprised to see it was put "On Hold".  I've been an SE user and mainly work in SO / Meta for years now.  I don't understand why this question was put on hold.

I started off with the `tl;dr;` of what I am trying to do.  I mentioned I knew about another question that might have been a cause for duplication but I stressed the difference, providing examples.

I then took time from my day to carefully post the question, provide screen shots, list out my current issues and my possible solution.  I stated what I was looking for.  I even got one solid answer...and then it is put on hold with no reason why.

I'm sorry I didn't waste two hours of my day formulating a question only to be put on hold with no reason.  The reason there is just not enough: "put on hold as too broad".  Broad about what?  I made a proposal and want to see what other professionals think about it and get feedback to help me.  As mentioned the first answer was great, and I'd hate to lose the momentum.

Please explain how I can make this question better to remove its current status, as it stands its not a pleasant experience so far :(.

Comment: @Devin - Please address this meta post concerning the linked question.

Comment: @JohnGB - Please address this meta post concerning the linked question.

Comment: I submitted an edit. See if you think it is clearer or missing any information

Comment: @Midas - It looks good but how can we reopen this.

Comment: @JohnGB - Please look at the edits and hopefully we can agree to open this now?

Answer (score 1):

I've re-read the question and I still believe it was the right call to put it on hold.  So although it is a well presented and interesting question, it doesn't fit into the Stack Exchange format for the following reasons:

> My question is I am not a fan of the network shared folder. There are just too many cons associated with it. However, I feel like (since I haven't proposed this yet) I am oversimplifying things. What am I missing here, what makes the hierarchy structure so much better? How can I convince or what other things could I do to my proposal to make this easier or better.

- As you touch on many sub points, any answers would have to deal with each point to be complete answers, which makes the question too broad.
- You aren't presenting a UX problem.  You're saying "I don't like x and I want an alternative", which immediately makes answers primarily opinion based.  It could be that a folders structure makes the most sense for a given problem, but your elimination of a prospective solution offhand negates that.  Think of the question and answer as a pair which is not aimed at you.  It needs to me maximally useful to all the future readers.

The biggest of the issues for me is it being too broad, which can fairly easily be fixed by limiting your question at the end to your main point. Secondary to that, don't dismiss a solution offhand, but rather give the goals you need to achieve which would disqualify that solution.

Comment: Forget the fact that I said I don't like x.  You can easily edit that out.  After you edit that out please reread the question.  I am asking specifically about what else I can do to change from a hierarchically structured method to flat based.  I even had an excellent answer.  I can't vote you down or up due to my rep.  But the question stands and I believe it is a good one.  Please edit what you feel is unnecessary.

Comment: I feel like you missed the main point in my response.  The biggest issue is it being too broad.  The answer to your question doesn't cover all the questions, so how will you compare it to another answer which covers a different set of your questions?  That is exactly what the "too broad" designation is about.

Comment: I don't agree with you and am sad to say this is the first time I am frustrated with an SE site.

Comment: What specifically don't you agree with?

Comment: The community has made some crucial edits to make this a better question - please think about reopening this question.

Comment: Although still borderline, the edited question is less broad, and hence I have re-opened it.